# Get byte array from .zip file in memory, without writing anything to disk

Tags: c#, stream, c#-ziparchive

I'm trying to take an existing .zip file (I get it from an api as byte array), take some files from it, and make a new .zip file. Then return that new .zip file as byte array. The catch is that all of this should be done in memory, without writing any actual files to disk.

So I have this setup. First memory stream and ziparchive is used for the orignal zip file. Second stream and archive represents the second zip that will only contained filtered items from the first zip.

```
        using var downloadedRepoStream = new MemoryStream(binaryRepo);
        using var downloadedRepoArchive = new ZipArchive(downloadedRepoStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, true);

        var entriesToExtract = downloadedRepoArchive.Entries; //add some filtering

        using var subRepoStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var subRepoArchive = new ZipArchive(subRepoStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true);
```

Then I go through each entry and copy contents over to the second zip.

```
        foreach (var entry in entriesToExtract)
        {
            var entryName = entry.FullName.Split('/', 2)[1];
            using var entryStream = entry.Open();

            var subRepoEntry = subRepoArchive.CreateEntry(entry.FullName);
            using var subRepoEntryStream = subRepoEntry.Open();

            await entryStream.CopyToAsync(subRepoEntryStream);
        }
```

Finally, I need to return that second ziparchive as byte array. I assumed I that I could just call MemoryStream.ToArray(), but the MemoryStream, used by the second ZipArchive, remains empty, despite ZipArchive having files. So how do I get byte[] from ZipArchive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not closing the new `ZipArchive` before looking at the stream. You can do this simply by using the old style `using` block

```cs
using var downloadedRepoStream = new MemoryStream(binaryRepo);
using var downloadedRepoArchive = new ZipArchive(downloadedRepoStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, true);

var entriesToExtract = downloadedRepoArchive.Entries; //add some filtering

using var subRepoStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var subRepoArchive = new ZipArchive(subRepoStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    foreach (var entry in entriesToExtract)
    {
        var entryName = entry.FullName.Split('/', 2)[1];
        using var entryStream = entry.Open();

        var subRepoEntry = subRepoArchive.CreateEntry(entry.FullName);
        using var subRepoEntryStream = subRepoEntry.Open();

        await entryStream.CopyToAsync(subRepoEntryStream);
    }
}

subRepoStream.Position = 0;
```

Note that `async` doesn't make a huge amount of sense when using `MemoryStream` as it's all sync anyway.

It's a shame there is no rename facility on `ZipArchiveEntry`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following to work with minor tweaks.
You appear to be missing the step where you set the position you wish to start reading from: subRepoStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

```
byte[] binaryRepo = ...
using MemoryStream downloadedRepoStream = new MemoryStream(binaryRepo);
using ZipArchive downloadedRepoArchive = new ZipArchive(downloadedRepoStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, false);

ReadOnlyCollection<ZipArchiveEntry> entriesToExtract = downloadedRepoArchive.Entries; //add some filtering

using MemoryStream subRepoStream = new MemoryStream();
using ZipArchive subRepoArchive = new ZipArchive(subRepoStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false);

foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in entriesToExtract)
{
    using Stream entryStream = entry.Open();
    
    ZipArchiveEntry subRepoEntry = subRepoArchive.CreateEntry(entry.FullName);
    using Stream subRepoEntryStream = subRepoEntry.Open();
    
    await entryStream.CopyToAsync(subRepoEntryStream);
}

// before reading the stream you need to set the position to the beginning.
subRepoStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

byte[] data = subRepoStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: Can't be the case. Checked with debugger. MemoryStream is always empty. It never receives any bytes to begin with.

Comment: You may want to check your input. Able to reproduce with a known good zip file with single entry. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wkkeayhssufbht9/ZiptoZipToMemoryStream.PNG?dl=0

Comment: You need to close the `ZipArchive` before using `ToArray`, ergo you need the old-fashioned `using()` block rather than `using var`

Comment: To second @Charlieface I have seen some instances where the new using declarations introduced in c#8 doesn't behave as I would expect. My first go-to when running into strange behavior is to convert them back to "old" style using blocks. No question when a resource is disposed when it lives between {}

Comment: @Charlieface You're correct, that indeed was the problem. I need to dispose ziparchive before accessing bytes from MemoryStream. Of course leaveOpen must be set to true inside ZipArchive's constructor. Create an answer and I'll mark it as accepted, if you're into that. If not, I can create it and mention you.
EDIT: Oops. Seems like you already created one.